Laravel Breeze prevent bail for password field, return all errors
Currently, Laravel Breeze seems to use bail default for the password field. So it does not return all errors at once.
Is there a way to prevent the bail for the password field using Breeze?
In my case I want to return all errors for the specific fields (in this case password).
Best would be if I could overwrite it similiar to how I did it for its validation in my AppServiceProvider:
        Password::defaults(function () {
            return Password::min(8)
                ->letters()
                ->numbers()
                ->symbols()
                ->mixedCase()
                ->uncompromised();
        });


uncompromised automatically adds the bail rule to the validation chain. To overcome your have to create new rule for this and comment uncompromised in password default
